# "if each one of us could recycle his/her waste" or "if each one of us could recycle their waste"

Tags: pronouns

Could I say "their" instead of "his/ her" as I wrote in the examples below?

"If each one of us could recycle his/her waste..."

vs

"If each one of us could recycle their waste...."

Comment: Many people (including me) are quite happy with [singular "they"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), a usage which has been around for at least 600 years. Some people object to it.

Comment: But in this case, _our waste_ is an alternative that works.

Comment: Thank you for your help!